# What is the difference between Global Variable and SharedPreferences android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am a new developer and I couldn't understand the difference between Global Variable and shared Preferences because the two can store the username and password from login page then use it in whole application.
Like access to the user's profile.With user's profile what is better to use?In general, when to use shared Preferences and when to use Global Variable?

Also I see in use sharedPreferences the user just have login one time to use app every time if he is not do logout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Global variable actually it's a parameter of the object. Lifetime of Global variable associate with object. I don't know exactly you create global variable (Example inside Activity, Application or Singleton...) but when User kill app it will be clean.
2. SharedPreferences actually it is xml file format, you can store key-value to it and it still alive until User Uninstall App or Clear Data App in Setting.

Basically, if Global variable using when you only want it alive in object declare it. In case you want to keep data even app kill you should using Database or SharedPreferences, SharedPreferences good with simple data type or some settings of you app

Comment: So if I want user login to main activity directly after first login  and he will  can access his profile without having to go through each time on the login page I have to use SharedPreferences It is true?

Comment: It's true. Are you login with backend server. After you login success you store it and user no need login again when open app again

Comment: What if you have more properties which are used throughout the application. Example: the profile id is what you want to store in shared preferences but other properties such as name or alias are seen throughout the application. Does it make sense to use shared preferences for them?